# ML train/test jobs with data as huge S3 csv or directly from a preprocessed Relational or NoSql DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, architecture, devops, amazon-sagemaker

I started working on some ML Ops project on AWS SageMaker, and I have a question about the way of storing/processing data. I have the DB of a company with tens of millions of invoices and clients that should be cleaned/transformed a bit for some classification and regression jobs. What would be the best approach: to make a new DB and develop ETL jobs that take the data from the standard DB, clean and transform it and put it into the “ML DB” (then I directly use this data for my models) or make jobs that take the data from the standard DB, process it and saves it as huge CSV files in S3 buckets? Intuitively, it seems that Relational DB -> process -> NoSql/Relational DB is a better approach than Relational DB -> process -> huge CSV file. I didn’t find anything about this on Google and all the AWS SageMaker docs are using CSV files on S3 as example and are not mentioning anywhere about making ML pipelines directly with relational stored data. What would be the best approach and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach sounds fine:

- The original data is left as-is in case you need to repeat the process later (perhaps with changes / improvements).
- The system will work for any data source once you plumb it in; i.e. you can re-use the transformation and load parts.

I don't know anything about SageMaker, etc, or the whole CVS thing, but once you have the data in your ML DB you can obviously export it to any format you like later, like CVS.